# Indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, indexing

I've only started using INDEXes in my MySQL database and I'm a little unsure if what I have in mind will work. I have a TEXT field that can store a large body of text and will need to be searched, along with another id INT field. If I have an INDEX on say my id_column field and a FULLTEXT index on my text_column, will MySQL use both in a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id_column='123' AND MATCH(text_column) AGAINST(search_text)
```

??

Secondly, I have a group of columns that can be used frequently for searching in combination together. If I create a multi-column INDEX in these columns, the index wills till work if the columns used are together left-to-right in the index. But what happens if the user leaves out a particular column, say B, and searches using A, B, D in an index like (A, B, C, D) ???

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:

Yes, the query will use both indices.  `FULLTEXT` indices can be kind of tricky, however, so it's a good idea to read the MySQL documentation thoroughly on them and use `EXPLAIN` on your queries to make sure they are properly utilizing indices.

For question 2:

If you have a multiple column index, the index has to have the same columns in the same order as the query to be used.  So in your example, the index wouldn't be utilized.

`EXPLAIN` is a very powerful tool for understanding how queries use indices, and it's a good idea to use it frequently (especially on queries which are programatically generated).  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that MySQL will use both two indexes for the same table in one query.  In general, no.  But sometimes it activates an "index merge," searching both indexes and combining the results.

Not all queries can do this, however.  You should read about this feature here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-merge-optimization.html

Regarding multi-column indexes, if you have an index on columns A, B, C, D, and you do a search on columns A, B, D, then the index may be used, but only so far as it narrows down the search based on your conditions for columns A and B.

You can see evidence of this if you use EXPLAIN and look at the "ken_len" field.  The key_len will be the total number of bytes in the columns that are used in that multi-column index.  Fo example, if A, B, C, D are four 4-byte integers, the key_len could be as much as 16.  But if only A and B are used, the key_len will be 8.

Answer (score 0):

Given this query:

```
SELECT * FROM notes
    WHERE id_column='123'
      AND MATCH(text_column) AGAINST(search_text)
```

the only way the optimizer will perform it (to my knowledge) is to

1. Use `FULLTEXT(text_column)` to do the second part of the search, *then*
2. *Filter* out those without `id_column='123'`; no index will be used for this step.

That's the general rule when mixing `FULLTEXT` and non-fulltext indexes -- FULLTEXT first; no other indexes used.

However...  Here is a trick that sometimes speeds up complex queries:

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM (
        SELECT id   -- assuming this is the PRIMARY KEY
            FROM notes
            WHERE MATCH(text_column) AGAINST(search_text)
         ) AS a
    JOIN notes AS b   -- "self join"
        ON b.id = a.id    -- just the PK
    JOIN ((other tables)) ON ...
    WHERE ((other messy or bulky stuff)) ...
```

The idea is to use the subquery to condense down to a short list of small values (the ids), then reach back in (or futher JOIN) to get the bulky stuff.

For building optimal composite indexes for some simple queries, see [my index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).